# Better approach to force the users of an abstract class to define a specific value for a class attribute

Tags: python, abstract-class

I'm using Python 3.8 and I would like to create an abstract class that will be used by other subclasses to redefine or add methods and attributes that are not common with other subclasses.

All these subclasses *must* have an instance attribute (`my_value`) and a class attribute called `LENGTH`.

`LENGTH` is fixed: subclass users (who will initialize subclass objects) could not directly modify it because all object created from that subclass *must* have the same `LENGTH` defined by the subclass creator.

The first attempt I did to obtain that result was to use, in the abstract class, the decorators `@property`, `@classmethod` and `@abstractmethod` in this way:

```
class SuperAbstractClass(ABC):
[...]
    @property
    @classmethod
    @abstractmethod
    def LENGTH(cls):
        return NotImplementedError
```

In that way I solved the problem: when you define a subclass you also have to define `LENGTH`.

I also added a new problem regarding the fact that in the abstract class I'm also redefining the `__setattr__` magic method to ensure that a subclass value alway matches the `LENGTH` value, filling `my_value` with zeros (using the `zfill` method):

```
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        '''
        Every time a user will assign a value to "my_value", "__setattr__" will ensure
        that the value get filled by zeros to match the "LENGTH" value
        (example: with LENGTH=4, the value "A" will become "000A")
        '''
        if name == 'my_value':
            super(SuperAbstractClass, self).__setattr__(
                                                        'my_value',
                                                        value.zfill(SuperAbstractClass.LENGTH)
                                                        )
        else: # all the other assignment will not be modified
            super(SuperAbstractClass, self).__setattr__(name, value)
```

In this way I get an error because `zfill` tells me that need an `int` and at that time `LENGTH` is a property.

Now I came up with a solution that is not ideal: the users of my abstract class *have* to redefine `__init__` but ideally they can avoid to define `LENGTH` (in this example `LENGTH` is now called `length_to_reach`) and also I have the same code to every subclass:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class SuperAbstractClass(ABC):
    '''
    We want to force all subclasses to redefine "__init__" adding an hardcoded
    length to the "my_value" attribute: ideally the subclasses users should
    only be able define "my_value", not the "length_to_reach"
    '''
    @abstractmethod
    def __init__(self, my_value, length_to_reach):
        self.length_to_reach = length_to_reach
        self.my_value = my_value # NB: assignation managed by __setattr__

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        '''
        Every time a user will assign a value to "my_value", "__setattr__" will ensure
        that the value get filled by zeros to match the "length_to_reach" value
        (example: with length_to_reach=4, the value "A" will become "000A")
        '''
        if name == 'my_value':
            super(SuperAbstractClass, self).__setattr__(
                                                        'my_value',
                                                        value.zfill(self.length_to_reach)
                                                        )
        else: # all the other assignment will not be modified
            super(SuperAbstractClass, self).__setattr__(name, value)


class SubClassOne(SuperAbstractClass):
    LENGTH = 12
    def __init__(self, my_value):
        super(SubClassOne, self).__init__(my_value, SubClassOne.LENGTH)

class SubClassTwo(SuperAbstractClass):
    LENGTH = 9
    def __init__(self, my_value):
        super(SubClassTwo, self).__init__(my_value, SubClassTwo.LENGTH)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = SubClassOne("ValueOne")
    b = SubClassTwo("ValueTwo")
    print(f'\na.my_value: {a.my_value} is now filled to the length of {a.LENGTH}')
    print(f'\nb.my_value: {b.my_value} is now filled to the length of {b.LENGTH}')

#*Output:*
#
#a.my_value: 0000ValueOne is now filled to the length of 12
#
#b.my_value: 0ValueTwo is now filled to the length of 9
```

My final question is: what is the best method to obtain that? Should I try to avoid abstract class users to define some attributes because is not very pythonic? Do I totally approach my needs from the wrong way?

Comment: What is your actual goal? This is probably way too complicated.

Comment: My goal are force creator of subclasses to define certain elements and prevent all the common logics to be repeated every subclass

Comment: Yes, but why? What are you going to do with that? What would be the problem if you don't force it?

Comment: In this project ideally SuperAbstractClass is a "connector", an interface that take information from my main program, translate it to external programs and viceversa. With this method every external program creator has to a define a subclass specific for them external program, for that reason I want to help them to forcing the definition of "least common denominator" attributes and defining the common method logic in the abstract class.